# Query won't return true on successful execute()

Tags: php, pdo

MariaDB server version is 10.1.21.

Below is my Database class which is used in the User class to add users to the DB. The `execute()` method doesn't seem to return `true` when saving users to the DB though the users get added.

```
<?php

class Database {
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;       // DB handler
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        // set DSN i. e. data source name
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this -> host.";dbname=".$this -> dbname;
        // set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // create a new PDO instance
        try {
            $this -> dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this -> user, $this -> pass, $options);       // connector to DB
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            $this -> error = $ex -> getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this -> stmt = $this -> dbh -> prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this -> stmt -> bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this -> stmt -> execute();
    }

    public function resultset() {
        $this -> execute();
        return $this -> stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);       // FETCH_OBJ to fetch object from DB. Could be associative array
    }

    public function single() {
        $this -> execute();
        return $this -> stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function rowCount() {
        return $this -> stmt -> rowCount();
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this -> dbh -> lastInsertId();
    }

    public function beginTransaction() {
        return $this -> dbh -> beginTransaction();
    }

    public function endTransaction() {
        return $this -> dbh -> commit();
    }

    public function cancelTransaction() {
        return $this -> dbh -> rollback();
    }
}
```

The User class code is below. The `execute()` method in the `public function register($data)` doesn't seem to return `true` either on account only the `false` case gets executed in another code piece. Cutting the `public function register($data)` short with `return true;` just above `if ($this -> db -> execute()) {...}` allows to receive the `success` message.

```
<?php

class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> db = new Database();
    }

    // register user
    public function register($data) {
        $this -> db -> query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, avatar, username, password, about, last_activity) VALUES (:name, :email, :avatar, :username, :password, :about, :last_activity)");
        $this -> db -> bind(':name', $data['name']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':email', $data['email']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':avatar', $data['avatar']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':username', $data['username']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':password', $data['password']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':about', $data['about']);
        $this -> db -> bind(':last_activity', $data['last_activity']);

        if ($this -> db -> execute()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // upload user avatar
    public function uploadAvatar() {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['avatar']['name']);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/gif")
                || ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/jpeg")
                || ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/jpg")
                || ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/pjpeg")
                || ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/x-png")
                || ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] == "image/png"))
                && ($_FILES['avatar']['size'] < 50000)
                && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
                    if ($_FILES['avatar']['error'] > 0) {
                        redirect('register.php', $_FILES['avatar']['error'], 'error');
                    } else {
                        if (file_exists('images/avatars/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name'])) {
                            redirect('register.php', "File already exists", 'error');
                        } else {
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], 'images/avatars/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
        } else {
            redirect('register.php', "Invalid file type", 'error');
        }
    }

    // user log in
    public function login($username, $password) {
        $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
        $this -> db -> bind(':username', $username);
        $this -> db -> bind(':password', $password);

        $row = $this -> db -> single();

        if ($this -> db -> rowCount() > 0) {
            $this -> setUserData($row);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // set user data
    public function setUserData($row) {
        $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row -> id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row -> username;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $row -> name;
    }

    // log user out
    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['name']);
        return true;
    }

    // get total number of users
    public function getTotalUsers() {
        $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
        $this -> db -> resultset();
        return $this -> db -> rowCount();
    }
}
```

The `false` case above gets processed in another code piece:

```
if ($user -> register($data)) {
                    redirect('index.php', 'You are registered and can now log in', 'success');
                } else {
                    redirect('index.php', 'Something went wrong with the registration', 'error');
                }
```

The only message that gets received is the `error` one.

Please suggest. I couldn't see what was wrong with the code. The users get added fine.

Comment: Side note, but the spaces in there like `$this -> stmt` are pretty annoying. I am surprised it even works. A lot of people follow the PSR-2 style: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#46-method-and-function-calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Database` `execute()` method returns nothing. Which is `NULL` which is `false`. So add `return` statement:

```
public function execute() {
    return $this -> stmt -> execute();
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!